# Задание переменной с помощью ссылки

Tags: php, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

```
<input name="text_01" type="text" value="" readonly="true">
<a name="123" onClick="document.getElementById('text_01').value = '123';">123</a>
```

В одной из своих тем задавал вопрос про альтернативу действий onclick. Нажимаем ссылку, и в текстбоксе нужное мне значение. Конструкция выше оказывается работает на 3,5 из 10 компьютеров, не включая браузер IE (в нем все). Разводить бессмысленные разговоры почему - не хочу.

Интересует, можно ли каким-то образом при нажатии на ссылку задать определенной переменной значение, а в "text_01" сделать ежесекундное обновление? Или любая альтернатива, главное чтобы работало.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем коде вы говорите document.getElementById('text_01'), то есть вы хотите получить элемент с ID(!!) = text_01. как вы заметили в вашем коде нет такого элемента с таким ID. Поэтому нужно использовать другую функцию: document.getElementByName('text_01') или добавить аттрибут ID в поле text_01

Comment: И не забываем: по стандарту id элемента должен совпадать с его name (если последнее указано).

Comment: А еще числовые name - не есть хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

попробуй через jQuery

```
<input name="text_01" id="text_01" type="text" value="" readonly="true">
<a name="123" onClick="$('#text_01').val('123');">123</a>
```